# Add Keycloak to express server to get kauth from request

Tags: express, keycloak, keycloak-connect, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I am trying to add Keycloak authentication to my ApolloServer using [keycloak-connect](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect).
I have setup my realm and login from `localhost:8080/auth`. However, I am having an issue getting kauth from my requests in the context function:

Currently I have the following setup:

```
   const kcConfig = {
        clientId: process.env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
        serverUrl: `localhost:808/auth`,
        realm: process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM,
        realmPublicKey: process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM_PUBLIC_KEY, 
    }

    const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore()

    app.use(session({
        secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET_STRING || 'this should be a long secret',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        store: memoryStore
    }))

    const keycloak = new Keycloak({
        store: memoryStore
    }, kcConfig as any)

    // Install general keycloak middleware
    app.use(keycloak.middleware({
        admin: graphqlPath
    }))
    
    // Protect the main route for all graphql services
    // Disable unauthenticated access
    app.use(graphqlPath, keycloak.middleware())
```

And then I try to access `req.kauth` in context like:

```
export interface GrantedRequest extends Request {
  kauth : {grant?: Grant};
}

const server = new ApolloServer({
    engine: {
        graphVariant: "current"
    },
    context: ({req, res} : {
        req: GrantedRequest,
        res: any
    }) => {
      console.log(req.kauth) // this line prints an empty object
      return {
        req,
        res,
        kauth: req.auth
      }
    },
    schema,
    playground: {
        settings: {
            "request.credentials": "same-origin"
        }
    }
});
```

However, I am not able to retrieve the kauth property from my request. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Keycloak authentication is not used until you define a resource which is protected. Compare to comment in https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/blob/master/keycloak.js#L92

Because you only define the `keycloak.middleware()` function, does not mean, that your resoures are protected.

To achieve login and receive access token from keycloak, you need to use `keycloak.protect()` or `keycloak.checkSso()` or `keycloak.enforcer()`. Therefore you have to assign these as request-handler to either URL

`app.get('/proteced-resource', keycloak.protect())`

or application

`app.use(keycloak.protect())`.